# How can I adjust the time that automatically reduces the brightness of screen?

Tags: power-management, brightness

At the moment it uses just a few seconds of inactivity after that ubuntu reduces the brightness of my screen. Where do i find the option to increase this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the "Regard computer as idle after" slider on System → Preferences → Screensaver:

[image]

Or the [gconf key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) `/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_time`, which you can set thusly:

```
gconftool --type int --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_time 120
```

which will set the timeout to 120 seconds.

Comment: thanks, it's the gconf key. It was default set to 10 seconds. For others who are interested in this issue. You can easily check what's the value of the key via gconf-editor. press Alt + F2 and then type in gconf-editor and search for the key as Iain posted.

Comment: the gconf key does not work anymore. how can this be done in ubuntu 11.10/gnome3 ??

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting in the menu "System / Settings / Power management". This setting can be changed if you're running on battery.

(I have the Swedish GUI so I hope I remembered the English menu names correctly! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must change the value of this key (which I made it a mandatory key, because I didnt want the users to change it.)

here's the key in gnome2 when your run the gonf-editor :
/desktop/gnome/session/idle_delay